# JsonMappingException when serializing avro generated object to json

Tags: java, json, serialization, avro

I used avro-tools to generate java classes from avsc files, using:

```
java.exe -jar avro-tools-1.7.7.jar compile -string schema myfile.avsc
```

Then I tried to serialize such objects to json by ObjectMapper,
but always got a JsonMappingException saying "not an enum" or "not a union".
In my test I create the generated object using it's builder or constructor.
I got such exceptions for objects of different classes...

Sample Code:

```
ObjectMapper serializer = new ObjectMapper(); // com.fasterxml.jackson.databind
serializer.register(new JtsModule()); // com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts
...
return serializer.writeValueAsBytes(avroConvertedObject); // => JsonMappingException
```

I also tried many configurations using: serializer.configure(...) but still failed.
**Versions:** Java 1.8, jackson-datatype-jts 2.3, 
jackson-core 2.6.5, jackson-databind 2.6.5, jackson-annotations 2.6.5

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: I also experiencing this problem.

Comment: Yes, I solved it. The point is to use one library end-to-end.
I found a way to use the avro-tools also for json serialization.
Sorry I can't give you a sample code because I'm at a vacation these days and I've got no access to my work sources...
HTH

Comment: I solved this in a different way.  I copied the velocity templates from the avro distribution into my project and added   @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore on all SHEMA$ properties and getter methods.

Comment: @Amir is your sample code from controller?

Answer (score 17):

If the `SCHEMA` member is really the case (we don't see the full error message), then you can switch it off. I use a mixin to do it, like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AvroGenerTests
{
  abstract class IgnoreSchemaProperty
  {
    // You have to use the correct package for JsonIgnore,
    // fasterxml or codehaus
    @JsonIgnore abstract void getSchema();
  }

  @Test
  public void writeJson() throws IOException {
    BookAvro b = BookAvro.newBuilder()
      .setTitle("Wilk stepowy")
      .setAuthor("Herman Hesse")
      .build();
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    om.addMixIn(BookAvro.class, IgnoreSchemaProperty.class);
    om.writeValue(new File("plik_z_gen.json"), b);
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for the solution. For anyone looking to ignore same method in a hierarchy of classes the following worked for me.   
**om.addMixIn(Object.class, IgnoreSchemaProperty.class)**

Comment: i tried similar however, I am getting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Comment: My avro schema has many Logical Types, I am getting this error even after following this solution - Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not an enum: {"type":"int","logicalType":"date"}

Comment: Hi, I know I might be a bit late to this, but I ran into the "Infinite Recursion" issue after following the exact instructions as the answer.
Only change I had to make was add another @JsonIgnore for SpecificData in the MixIn. Add the following line into the IgnoreSchemaProperty MixIn
`@JsonIgnore SpecificData getSpecificData()`

Answer (score 5):

2022 Avro field names

```
abstract class IgnoreSchemaPropertyConfig {
   // You have to use the correct package for JsonIgnore,
   // fasterxml or codehaus
   @JsonIgnore
   abstract void getClassSchema();

   @JsonIgnore
   abstract void getSpecificData();

   @JsonIgnore
   abstract void get();

   @JsonIgnore
   abstract void getSchema();
}


public class AvroGenerateJSON
{
 
  public String convertToJson() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.addMixIn(BookAvro.class,IgnoreSchemaPropertyConfig.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jose, i had some exceptions related to {"type":"int","logicalType":"date"}, after adding all of these @JsonIgnore annotations I am now able to proceede

Comment: I'm confused what are you supposed to do with this abstract class?

Comment: Hi, I added the code extracted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70222480/7141579

Answer (score 3):

My req'ts got changed on me and I was told I needed to convert Avro objects straight to JSON without preserving any of the meta-data.  My other answer herein that specified a method convertToJsonString converts the entire Avro object to JSON so that using a de-encoder you can re-create the original Avro object as an Avro object.  That isn't what my mgt. wanted anymore so I was back to the old drawing board.

As a Hail Mary pass I tried using Gson and it works to do what I now had to do.  It's very simple:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String theJsonString = gson.toJson(object_ur_converting);
```

And you're done.

Comment: Top rated solution was not working for me, I suppose because I had logical types in avro schema and I was getting exception as mentioned at the end. This Solution works perfectly.. Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not an enum: {"type":"int","logicalType":"date"}

Answer (score 2):

After finding the code example at https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.avro.io.JsonEncoder I wrote a method that should convert any given Avro object (they extend GenericRecord) to a Json String.  Code:

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.JsonEncoder;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

// ... Class header etc. ...

public static <T extends GenericRecord> String convertToJsonString(T event) throws IOException {

    String jsonstring = "";

    try {
        DatumWriter<T> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<T>(event.getSchema());
        OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JsonEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(event.getSchema(), out);
        writer.write(event, encoder);
        encoder.flush();
        jsonstring = out.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("IOException occurred.", e);
        throw e;
    }

    return jsonstring;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Shivansh's answer. To add, there might be instances where we need to use the avro-generated pojo in other classes. Under the hood, spring uses jackson library in handling this so we need to override global jackson config by adding a class

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {
    public abstract IgnoreSchemaProperty {
          @JsonIgnore abstract void getSchema();
    }
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
          ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
          om.addMixIn(SpecificRecordBase.class, IgnoreSchemaProperty.class);
          return om;
    }
}
```

SpecificRecordBase -if we want to ignore the schema field from all avro generated classes. In this way, we can serialize/deserialize our avro classes and use it anywhere in our application without getting the issue.

Comment: Didn't work + too many basic syntax error

Answer (score 1):

The previous post answers the question correctly. I am just adding on to the previous answer. Instead of writing it to a file I converted it to a string before sending it as body in a POST request.

```
public class AvroGenerateJSON
{
  abstract class IgnoreSchemaProperty
  {
    // You have to use the correct package for JsonIgnore,
    // fasterxml or codehaus
    @JsonIgnore abstract void getSchema();
  }

  public String convertToJson() throws IOException {
    BookAvro b = BookAvro.newBuilder()
      .setTitle("Wilk stepowy")
      .setAuthor("Herman Hesse")
      .build();
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    om.addMixIn(BookAvro.class, IgnoreSchemaProperty.class);
    String jsonString = om.writeValueAsString(b);
    return jsonString;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing this issue when trying to use structured logging via [logstash-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder). Then you need to use a `JsonFactoryDecorator` implementation to add the mixin to ignore the problematic avro generated getters.

```
package the.package.path;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import net.logstash.logback.decorate.JsonFactoryDecorator;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase;


public class AvroJsonFactoryDecorator implements JsonFactoryDecorator {
    abstract class JacksonIgnoreAvroProperties {

        @JsonIgnore
        public abstract org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema();

        @JsonIgnore
        public abstract org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData getSpecificData();

        @JsonIgnore
        public abstract java.lang.Object get(int field$);

        @JsonIgnore
        public abstract org.apache.avro.Schema getSchema();
    }

    @Override
    public JsonFactory decorate(JsonFactory factory) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = (ObjectMapper) factory.getCodec();
        objectMapper.addMixIn(SpecificRecordBase.class, JacksonIgnoreAvroProperties.class);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

And then include the following in your logback config:

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
                <jsonFactoryDecorator class="the.package.path.AvroJsonFactoryDecorator"/>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
```